# Liquibase is trying to execute change-set which has already been executed previously and thus throwing error that table already exist

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

```java
    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase()  {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(vsDataSource());        
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:liquibase/avt_changelog_master.xml"); 
        return liquibase;
    }
```

This is how I am initializing liquibase through a spring boot application.

I have checked databasechangelog table and I can find that for that changeset entry is there and it has been executed successfully.

Why liquibase is not skipping that changeset and executing new unique changeset Ids.

Answer (score 10):

Problem could be with name of your changelog. If you executed that changelog from within other application/maven/... and you didn't specified the `logicalFilePath` then liquibase could think of it as a different changelog. Try to set `logicalFilePath` in your changelog definition and try to execute it then.

this is example:

```xml
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd"
                   logicalFilePath="db-changelog-master.xml">
```

Comment: Hi this solution did not work.  I have one master file avt_changelog_master.xml under which I am including path to different changelog files.                                                                                   Usually if liquibase finds entry of changeset Id in changelog table it should skip that, but in my case it is trying to execute the already executed changeset.

Comment: @DeepeshRathore or anyone else still facing the same issue, follow @bilak advice. add `logicalFilePath` and ensure value of `FILE_NAME` column in the `databasechangelog` table is the same as that of `logicalFilePath`.

Comment: In my case, I modified file name directly in databasechangelog table but with `classpath:/db.changelog/<changelog>` and in my `databaseChangeLog` file it was `/db.changelog/<changelog>`. After changing it to `/db.changelog/<changelog>` in databasechangelog table it worked. 

P.S. I was trying liquibase on demo project so I modified databasechangelog table entry directly, but you should not change the table entries directly.

Comment: @Omkar you lead me to the solution for my issue.
In my case, the main changelog.xml was put to the path /resources/db/changelogs/changelog.xml
but java was looking for a resource in /resources/db.changelogs/changelog.xml
that was why it didn't match it with the filename in the tables.
After moving it up to /resources/changeslogs/changelog.xml works fine

Comment: @FilipKubala kudos!!